# При при запросе к корню сайта не выполняется index.php, выводит No index

Tags: php, apache2

Подключил сайт к `apache`, всё было норм, пока страничка индекс была `html`, после того как я поменял расширения на `php` браузер выдал `No index` или обновите страницу.  Набрал `localhost` тоже самое и `php` отключился, хотя я его подключил к `apache`.Мне сказали, что это конфликт двух модулей. Как это разрешить. `php` подключается только когда я убираю код подключения к сайту    <VirtualHost *:80>        ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com        DocumentRoot C:/www/test.ru/www        ServerName test.ru        ErrorLog C:/www/test.ru/logs/error_log        CustomLog C:/www/test.ru/logs/access_log common    Как сделать так, чтоб и сайт работал и php?

Answer (score 3):

В конфигурации Apache:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Прописан? Если нет - допишите.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не понял, но есть подозрение, что поменяв расширение index.html на index.php, в файле вы оставили тот же код HTML. А надо уже PHP! Это не одно и то же. Если я понял неправильно, то прошу прощения! Но уж очень невнятно вы написали.

А вы случаем, не с [Денвером](http://www.denwer.ru/) ли работаете?

Comment: Да как-то разницы нету. PHP с кодом HTML работает отлично.

Comment: Но это несколько неправильно. Код HTML должен быть встроен в PHP при помощи <?phpecho ' [код HTML] ';?>, а не простым изменением расширения.

Comment: Если вы говорите о неправильности с точки зрения проектирования своего веб-приложения, тогда я согласен. Но в общем случае код HTML в PHP файле будет работать, я лишь это имел ввиду. Потому, что в ином случае, для чего выделять код через <?php ?>? Именно потому, что эта часть будет обрабатываться интерпретатором, а все остальное - нет.

Comment: Тут я с вами согласен, и даже плюсанул. Но всё же, если работает формально неверный код, то это не фича, а баг! Вот так дырки и получаются!

Comment: Почему же он не верный? В самом общем случае (не претендую на звание точность года), у вас есть HTML страничка, которая обрабатывается сервером, т.е. в соответствие с конфигурацией добавляются заголовки и отдается файл.В случае же PHP, через подключемый модуль, выдергивается код между <?php ?> и отдается интерпретатору, результат работы которого выдается обратно. Дальнейшая процедура почти ничем не отличается от обычного HTML.

Comment: Неверный формально, потому что PHP - это язык скриптовый, т.е предназначенный для исполнения, в то время, как HTML, опять-таки формально - это гипертекст, изначально для исполнения не предназначенный, в том смысле, что это не программа, а описание размётки страниц. Сейчас, правда, это всё смешалось, что вообще-то не совсем правильно.

Comment: Совершенно не вижу связи. HTML никто и никогда (резкова-то сказано) исполнять не будет, исполняется только код PHP, вся остальная "оболочка" в виде гипертекстовой разметки остается как есть.Ничего не смешалось, HTML это гипертекст, PHP - скриптовый язык. Вариантов реализации просто много, от включения в код PHP, разметки HTML и echo "<table></table>"; до шаблонизаторов, которые разделяют код и разметку.В любом случае обрабатываться код и разметка будут по-разному.